SSD upgrade iMac -> Stupid mistake?
I upgraded my old iMac with an SSD i had laying around.
Without thinking twice i took an spare SSD which was probably from an old laptop of mine..
I booted an live iso, it boots but as soon as i start installation i get a error message.
On gpartition i see that the disk is locked i have no permission to access the drive.
Is there any way i can forcefully wipe this disk? I removed the entire screen and installed it again, removing the SSD manually would be a huge pain i'd love to avoid.
Sorry for my bad English 

If there is a lock icon on the drive that means that it is mounted.  You will need to unmount the partition first through the gparted app.

WAs this drive NTFS and Windows hibernation or fast startup set hibernation flag locking drive? Is drive old MBR or gpt? For UEFI boot you need to use gpt. Force removal of hiberfil from Ubuntu
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If drive was used for installer, you can use dd like you would use for a flash drive. Force removal of hiberfil from Ubuntu
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Hello, thanks for the quick replies! I have tried unmounting the disk, target is busy, i have tried to force this action but it doesn't let me. This is an SSD with win11 on it.

This is an SSD with win11 on it -- Most likely that is the reason. You have to open Windows and turn off fast startup

Try the following.
Start a Live Ubuntu session
The upload is complete.
Open a terminal.
Run on it:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gparted
sudo fdisk -l

Fdisk will tell you which partitions your SSD has
Unmount them from largest to smallest with the command
sudo umount /dev/nvme0n1p4
sudo umount /dev/nvme0n1p3
sudo umount /dev/nvme0n1p2
sudo umount /dev/nvme0n1p1

Change /dev/nvme0n1p4 so it corresponds to your SSD
Then load gparted
sudo gparted

From Gparted, select the disk and create a new gpt partition table and the following partitions:
One 1 gb boot-efi or bios-grub, depending on how your PC boots

One 100 gb, ext4 for /

One   8 gb, swap for Swap

One of the remaining gigs, ext4 for /home

Apply the changes
Start the installation and in partitioning choose manual.
And select the partitions for / and for /home, Grub is installed by default

This worked, thank u. SSD is wiped & linux has been installed without problems! This Topic is solved

In gparted you should be able to unmount the partitions of your SSD and delete them. Then you should be able to install as normal.
